# Getting SHA256 digest of an APK programmatically android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an installed APK on my device, and I am trying to get the SHA256 digest of the same. Manually, I do it like this:

`apksigner verify --print-certs path/to/apk.apk` and use the SHA256 digest.

But I need to do the same thing programmatically, by passing the `package name` of the APK, I get the SHA256 digest. Is there anyway I can achieve it?

Comment: You can sign the apk, and check if the signature is intact.

Comment: @AagitoEx the APK is already signed, we just need to fetch the SHA256 digest.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this to generate SHA256 hash for Google SMS API. Hope this helps.

[AppSignatureHelper](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java)

Answer (score 0):

I am still relativly new to programming so not sure if there is a difference between SHA256 and SHA256 digest but if you follow these steps here up to step 3,after scrolling down to the answer: [Users are not saved/registered on the Firebase authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593962/users-are-not-saved-registered-on-the-firebase-authentication) You can use the same method and get the SHA 256 key. Hopefully this will Help!